# Geofence with mock GPS provider

Tags: android, gps, geofencing, android-geofence

I am currently making a Geofencing app for Android, and I followed their [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) but I can't seem to get the BroadcastReceiver to trigger correctly while using mock GPS Location app.

I am also starting Location Service who fetch location from hardware after every 10000 ms interval. I completely follow this [Github repository](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location).

```
    private void populateGeofenceList() {
    for (Map.Entry<String, LatLng> entry : Constants.BAY_AREA_LANDMARKS.entrySet()) {

        geofenceArrayList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                // Set the request ID of the geofence. This is a string to identify this
                // geofence.
                .setRequestId(entry.getKey())

                // Set the circular region of this geofence.
                .setCircularRegion(
                        entry.getValue().latitude,
                        entry.getValue().longitude,
                        Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS
                )

                // Set the expiration duration of the geofence. This geofence gets automatically
                // removed after this period of time.
                .setExpirationDuration(Constants.GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS)
                // Set the transition types of interest. Alerts are only generated for these
                // transition. We track entry and exit transitions in this sample.
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                        Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                .setLoiteringDelay(0)
                // Create the geofence.
                .build());
    }
}


    private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();

    // The INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER flag indicates that geofencing service should trigger a
    // GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER notification when the geofence is added and if the device
    // is already inside that geofence.
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);

    // Add the geofences to be monitored by geofencing service.
    builder.addGeofences(geofenceArrayList);


    // Return a GeofencingRequest.
    return builder.build();
}
```

Comment: add property of requesting geofence trigger info setLoiteringDelay(10000)

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions :

1. Check if you location adapter is on.
2. Check if you have you granted location [permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing#RequestGeofences).
3. Check if the value of latitude, longitude is right. Does google maps show the right location , where you are expecting the trigger.
4. Set dwell time (setLoiteringDelay(10000)) if required.
5. Have you setup BroadcastReceiver to receive callbacks as mentioned in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing#HandleGeofenceTransitions).